# Merge nested array of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, merge

In sample code nameA and nameB missing few dates when comparing with common_count.

So, the expected output hash must be present missing dates with value will be zero

Thank you in advance.

```
    "common_count"=>[
         {20190704=>0}, {20190705=>0}, {20190706=>0}, {20190707=>0},               
         {20190708=>0}, {20190709=>0}, {20190710=>0}, {20190711=>0}
        ]
   }

   {

    "nameA"=>[
         {20190704=>10} {20190706=>50}, {20190707=>10},               
         {20190708=>0}, {20190709=>10}, {20190710=>0}, {20190711=>40}
        ],

   "nameB"=>[
         {20190704=>30}, {20190707=>20},               
         {20190708=>3}, {20190709=>5}, {20190710=>0}, {20190711=>20}
        ], ..... etc
   }
```

```
   "nameA"=>[
         {20190704=>10}, {20190705=>0}, {20190706=>50}, {20190707=>10},               
         {20190708=>0}, {20190709=>10}, {20190710=>0}, {20190711=>40}
        ],

   "nameB"=>[
         {20190704=>30},{20190705=>0}, {20190706=>0} {20190707=>20},               
         {20190708=>3}, {20190709=>5}, {20190710=>0}, {20190711=>20}
        ],...etc
   }
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried, we won't do your homework for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply:

```ruby
entries = {
  "common_count"=>[
   {"20190704"=>0}, {"20190705"=>0}, {"20190706"=>0}, {"20190707"=>0},               
   {"20190708"=>0}, {"20190709"=>0}, {"20190710"=>0}, {"20190711"=>0}
  ],
  "nameA"=>[
   {"20190704"=>10}, {"20190706"=>50}, {"20190707"=>10},               
   {"20190708"=>0}, {"20190709"=>10}, {"20190710"=>0}, {"20190711"=>40}
 ],
 "nameB"=>[
   {"20190704"=>30}, {"20190707"=>20},               
   {"20190708"=>3}, {"20190709"=>5}, {"20190710"=>0}, {"20190711"=>20}
 ]
}

default = entries.delete("common_count")
default_map = default.inject(:merge)

merged_entries = entries.map do |nameKey, value|
  value_map = value.inject(:merge)
  merged_value_map = default_map.merge(value_map)
  merged_value = merged_value_map.map { |k, v| {k => v} }

  {nameKey => merged_value}
end.inject(:merge)
```

Notice that I had to convert an array of hashes to a single hash in order to merge the hashes' contents. Then I reverted the hash result to an array of hashes.

Comment: You can simplify `merged_entries` to just `entries.transform_values { |v| 
  default_map.merge(v.reduce(:merge)).map {|k,v| {k=> v}}}`, since you are mutating `entries` anyway. Now `entries` will be in the requested format.

Comment: Nice approach, check my answer also which goes in shorter way

Answer (score 0):

If you have input like below,

```
common_count = [{"20190704"=>0}, {"20190705"=>0}, {"20190706"=>0}, {"20190707"=>0}, {"20190708"=>0}, {"20190709"=>0}, {"20190710"=>0}, {"20190711"=>0}]

nameA = [{"20190704"=>10}, {"20190706"=>50}, {"20190707"=>10}, {"20190708"=>0}, {"20190709"=>10}, {"20190710"=>0}, {"20190711"=>40}]

nameB = [{"20190704"=>30}, {"20190707"=>20}, {"20190708"=>3}, {"20190709"=>5}, {"20190710"=>0}, {"20190711"=>20}]
```

You can run following to add missing keys from `common_count`,

```
[nameA, nameB].each do |arr|
  (common_count.map(&:keys).flatten - arr.map(&:keys).flatten).each do |missing|
    arr.push({missing => 0})
  end
end
```